# Laravel route service provider not triggered for domain key

Tags: laravel, routes, laravel-5, service-provider

I’m creating a SaaS app (who isn’t?) and like most SaaS apps, I’ve taking the account subdomain approach. My routes file looks like this:

```
$router->group(['domain' => '{account}.example.com'], function($router)
{
    $router->get('/', function()
    {
        return response('Hello, world.');
    });
});
```

I then decided to add some route parameter validation and binding in my `RouteServiceProvider` file:

```
public function boot(Router $router)
{
    parent::boot($router);

    $router->pattern('account', '[a-z0-9]+');

    $router->bind('account', function($subdomain)
    {
        return Account::whereSubdomain($subdomain)->firstOrFail();
    });
}
```

However, these don’t actually seem to be triggered. I know this as I can put something like `dd('here?')` in the `bind` call, and it’s never triggered. I can also reduce my `account` pattern filter to something like `[0-9]+` and it’ll still be matched if I include letters in the subdomain.

What am I doing wrong? How can I get route patterns and bindings to work on variables in the `domain` key of my route group?

Comment: Is the provider loaded in `config/app.php`?

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes. It’s just a standard Laravel app, and I’ve not removed the default `RouteServiceProvider`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out moving any bindings to the `map` method (instead of the `boot`) method works, and pattern filters need to go inside the route group definition, like so:

```
$router->group(['domain' => '{account}.example.com'], function($router)
{
    $router->pattern('account', '[a-z0-9]+');

    $router->get('/', function()
    {
        return response('Hello, world.');
    });
});
```

Not ideal, so any one knows how to have filter patterns be kept in my `RouteServiceProvider` class so they’re not littered in my routes file, then would love to hear from you.